# Building Qt from source on OS X 10.10

Tags: qt, qt5.4

I've tried to build a minimalist framework using `qt-opensource-mac-x64-clang-5.4.0-beta.dmg` with:

```
./configure -silent -nomake examples -nomake tests  -platform macx-clang
```

but the build process fails miserably:

```
../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/mac/ScrollAnimatorMac.mm:891:26: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<NSFileManagerDelegate>' with an rvalue of type 'PtrType' (aka 'ChromiumWebCoreObjCWebScrollbarPainterDelegate *')
    [painter setDelegate:m_verticalScrollbarPainterDelegate.get()];
```

The latest sources in git also give this error, even if I remove the bogus module with `-skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebkit-examples`. Any ideas how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from QtWebEngine so try

```
-skip qtwebengine
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have specific requirements, it's best to let [homebrew](http://brew.sh) handle the details. I recently compiled pyqt, which also needs qt and it worked fine on OSX 10.10:

`brew install qt`

Comment: Why "always best"? What if I want to fine-tune my qt installation (select specific modules, compiler, etc)? If you don't need to tune details, just click on the .dmg and you have Qt!

Comment: Qt on homebrew also comes with many options. If you miss some and they make sense for others as well, why not add them there? With *always best* I meant *best* for average users who just want to use QT without diving into the details.

Comment: The problem with using brew is that its using Qt5.3.2 which only has minimum support for 10.10. The original poter is asking about Qt5.4.0 (beta at the time of posting)